# Linking user Id and installation Id in Parse iOS

Tags: ios, parse-platform

In the Data Browser pane of my Parse dashboard, I see Installation and User classes. However, for a specific user on a specific device, the objectIds don't match. Now, the channels a user has subscribed to is only visible in the installation class. Is there any way of linking the user id (from user class) to the installation id so that it is possible to know which channels a user has subscribed to? Any link to a tutorial or a solution would be appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
// Associate the device with a user
PFInstallation *installation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
installation[@"user"] = [PFUser currentUser];
[installation saveInBackground];
```

This will put the user in a column "user" in the Installation table, the column would be a pointer to the _User table.

Comment: Correct, concise and awesome!

Comment: Do you do this in didRegisterForRemoteNotifications callback in AppDelegate?

Comment: @c0d3Junk13 you can do it anywhere you want

Answer (score 2):

Swift 2.1 Variant

```
let installation: PFInstallation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
installation["user"] = PFUser.currentUser()
installation.saveInBackground()
```