# Send a push notification on a single device through heroku parse server

Tags: ios, node.js, heroku, push, parse-server

I am using heroku parse server app and trying to send push notification to a single device based on the user data available in mongodb. I am using cloud function showing below:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("iosPush", function(request, response) {

var user = request.user;
var params = request.params;
var someKey = params.someKey
var data = params.data

var pushQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
pushQuery.equalTo('deviceType', 'ios'); // targeting iOS devices only
pushQuery.equalTo("someKey", someKey)

Parse.Push.send({
    where: pushQuery, // Set our Installation query
    data: data
}, { success: function() {
    console.log("#### PUSH OK");
}, error: function(error) {
    console.log("#### PUSH ERROR" + error.message);
}, useMasterKey: true});

response.success('success');
});
```

I am hitting a curl request, to check the push notification like -

```sh
curl \
-X POST \
-H "X-Parse-Application-Id: myAppId" \
-H "X-Parse-Master-Key: masterkey" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d { "where": { "user_id": "cedsGn98ja" }, "data": { "alert": "Hello, Parse!"  } }
```

http://myapp.herokuapp.com/parse/functions/iosPush

The push is working but it is sending on all devices. I want a way so that I can send it on a single device.

Thanks...

Comment: I tried like this 

curl -X POST -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: myAppId" -H "X-Parse-Master-Key: masterkey" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{  "where": {    "user": {  "__type": "Pointer", "className": "_User",   "objectId": "cedsGn98ja"  } },  "data": {    "alert": "new one2"  } }' http://myapp.herokuapp.com/parse/functions/iosPush

But still same. push is sending on all devices instead of only this user

Answer (score 3):

I used the following code to send a notification from user 1 to user 1 for testing. You'll need to modify 'someKey' to target the specific user for your use case. Don't forget to [link your installation to the user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25300107/linking-user-id-and-installation-id-in-parse-ios) in your app delegate.

swift

```
let text = "\(PFUser.current()!.username!) followed you, or whatever you want this to say";
let data = [
        "badge" : "Increment",
        "alert" : text,
    ]
    let request: [String : Any] = [
        "someKey" : PFUser.current()!.objectId!,
        "data" : data
    ]
    print(PFUser.current()!.objectId!)
    print("sending push notification...")
    PFCloud.callFunction(inBackground: "pushToFollowers", withParameters: request as [NSObject : AnyObject], block: { (results:AnyObject?, error:NSError?) in
        print("push \(String(describing: results!))")
        if error == nil {
            print (results!)
        }
        else {
            print (error!)
        }
    } as? PFIdResultBlock)
```

cloud code

```
  Parse.Cloud.define("pushToFollowers", function (request, response) {
  console.log("Inside pushToFollowers");
  var params = request.params;
  var user = request.user;
  var sessionToken = user.getSessionToken();
  var someKey = request.someKey;
  var data = params.data;

 // Set our query to target specific user 
  var recipientUser = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
  recipientUser.equalTo("objectId", request.params.someKey);

// Set our installation query
  var pushQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
   pushQuery.equalTo('deviceType', 'ios');
   pushQuery.matchesQuery('user', recipientUser); 
   pushQuery.find({ useMasterKey: true }).then(function(object) {
        response.success(object); 
        console.log("pushQuery got " + object.length);
        }, function(error) {
          response.error(error);
            console.error("pushQuery find failed. error = " + error.message);
    });

  // Send push notification to query
  Parse.Push.send({
    where: pushQuery,
    data: data  
  }, { useMasterKey: true })
    .then(function() {
      // Push sent!
      console.log("#### push sent!");
    }, function(error) {
      // There was a problem :(
      console.error("#### push error" + error.message);
    });
response.success('success, end of pushToFollowers')
});
```

Comment: @s.jain Please accept the answer if this is working for you. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Is `someKey` going to be unique for all users? If it isn't, your push should be sending to all installations with that matching key. In order to send to a specific user, you would want to add a query constraint for the `user` field on the Installation object. This could be the sole query constraint if you want to blast it to all of that user's devices, or you could target a specific device by using a deviceId or installationId.

Comment: Thank you. Can  you please explain how should I write query for installation Id? I tried like "where": {    "user": "instalation_id"  } but it was not worked. Also can you please explain how to use somekey?

Comment: The problem is that "where" condition is not working. I have tried everything but push is sending to all users.